# Вопрос который решаю 4 дня

Tags: php, mvc

Всем привет. 
такая проблема я учу php и я придумал пример благодаря которому мой личный бизнес и мои знания php вырастут до новых высот )
Это будет что-то вроде бух учета и CRM

но проблема в том что я не знаю с чего начать ну mvc я не смогу сделать а фреймворк мне не нужен так как нужно сначала язык выучить. 
дайте совет на чем лучше создать делать эту систему.
Если делать грубо говоря страницу и в ней php то будет очень большие непонятки с html css js и php тоже так как прогнозирую  более 50 страниц

Comment: Твоя идея должна приносить прибыл. Чтобы была прибыл - нужно инвестировать. Это замкнутый круг). По-этому, тебе проще будет найти человека который это все дело за деньги реализует, а ты уже будешь руководить. Если нет денег, читай первый ответ)

Comment: Моя идея в том что-бы первое изучить php а для этого уже есть идея где я могу увеличить свои знания  то есть этот проект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните вот с чего.

1. Возьмите блокнот в клеточку, карандаш, ластик.
2. Запишите по пунктам все, что хотите реализовать в этой своей мега системе.
3. Нарисуйте схему своей программы, основные экраны, источники данных.
4. Нарисуйте сплошные стрелочки, показывающие, как происходят переходы между экранами.
5. Нарисуйте прерывистые линии, показывающими как циркулируют данные..
6. Критически на все это посмотрите, вырвите использованные листы из блокнота и сожгите в пепельнице.
7. Вернитесь к пункту 1 (повторять до просветления)
8. Начинаете писать код.

Comment: я это все понимаю/ 
проблема в том что я понимаю для того что-бы было более менее правильно нужно что-то вроде mvc вот в чем беда

Comment: @AndryLomakin mvc - это всего лишь один из многих паттернов проектирования. Сейчас он в моде, но это не значит, что без него никак. Ну и к слову, его нельзя "сделать", им можно руководствоваться.

Comment: В любом случае сначала придется учить HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, MYSQL А только потом приступать к изучению MVC паттерна. Так что если хотите все изучить все в кратчайшие возможные сроки, можете взять книжку "Создаем динамические веб-сайты с помощью PHP, MySQL, JavaScript, CSS и HTML5" И потихоньку придти к пониманию как все это будет работать. А вообще CRM можно и без использования каких либо сложных инструментов собрать, даже на чистом PHP

Comment: где-то на ruSO я эти пункты уже читал)